# Get attribute in another name in Sequelize?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have a table "facilities" with columns "titleEn" and "titleRu". I want to select attribute title depending on passed language code and call it just "title".
So I've written next code:

```
const facilities = await this.facilityRepository.findAll({
        where: {parentId: 0},
        attributes: [
            'id',
            sequelize.literal('"Facility"."title' + lang + '" as "title"'),
            'slug',
        ],
    });
```

It generated the next query:

```
SELECT "id", "Facility"."titleEn" as "title", "slug" FROM "facilities" AS "Facility" WHERE "Facility"."parentId" = 0;
```

I get every data I wanted from DB. But "title" property is missing in sequelize object. I get "id" and "slug" only.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that I have to declare attribute as virtual in model

```
  @Column(DataType.VIRTUAL)
  title: string;
```